# Display image on Html page

Tags: javascript, java, html, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm trying to display a static image located in the same folder as my Html file but it seems I can't get the right path for it to display correctly. The application I'm developing is an atlassian plugin that also includes a java backend to get Data from the Database and I'm displaying it on the frontend using HTML and javascript, the whole application runs on a webserver as a Plugin. Both the image and the Html file are located in here: `D:\clone4\project\src\main\resources\templates\scheduleraction`

The URL path for the web application is:

`https://staging.com/jira/secure/SchedulerAction!default.jspa`

I tried many ways and this is the last one :

`<img  src="/SchedulerAction!default.jspa/piechart.jpg" alt="pie-chart">`

I need to add the correct path in the "src" so the client can retrieve the image from my Files on the webserver. I would love any hint or help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should use exact path like `./Image.png`. And avoid using Images out of the static HTML file located directory

Comment: The image is located in the same directory as my Html and ./piechart.jpg is also not working. The image is empty and it points to : https://staging.com/jira/secure/piechart.jpg

Comment: Maybe the Cross-Origin does not allow to display or serve the image

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a service to upload that image and use the provided url.
Such as https://imgur.com/. After upload it, use into the `src` the correct url with the filetype extension.

Comment: Tried that and it worked but some users in other countries are using VPN to access the application and so they can't see the image because of VPN restrictions since image uploads websites are being stopped